# Nested if solution in Microsoft excel for partial matching strings

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write a formula for nested if in one of the columns in excel.
For ex:
I want to automatically get the values in one column based on the matching values in another column.
Lets say the two columns are A and B.
If A contains any string like "Bank" then i want the column B to be FGT_Bank_OSP.
If A contains any string like "PDM" then i want the column B to be "FGT_PDM_OSP.
Similarly i have 25 other values.

I tried to use something like this but tjis is not working.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DMT_Bank_Sensitive",E5)), "DMT_Bank_SEN_OSP", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DMT_PDM_Sensitive",E5)), "DMT_PDM_SEN_OSP"),"No")
```

Sample Data :[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYORb.png)
Do we have any easy way or any function in excel?

[Sample Data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oobyk.png)

Comment: Do you have a visual representation of your sample data and expected results?

Comment: Added the sample data with the expected result. The requirement is pretty straightforward to check for a pattern in a column and accordingly update the value in another col.

Comment: I'd say a VLOOKUP applied on a list of possible input and output. Do the dat in Col1 have always an underscore to delimit our target? Do the data always start with "FDG_"?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey- The data in col 1 might not have a _ and its not  delimiter.

Comment: Not sure how to use vlookup here as we are matching based on the pattern/contains.

Comment: Do you always have a value of three words concatenated in columns through underscore? And are you always interested in the second word, where you would want to change the third word? Also, are all values in column A preceded by `FDG_`? Also, it would help if you include all your 25 values with their respective counterparts =)

Comment: Is something like this already good? `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DMT_Bank_Sensitive",E5)),"DMT_Bank_Sensitive","") & IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DMT_PDM_Sensitive",E5)),"DMT_PDM_Sensitive","")`. It should be fairly simple to edit for all the 25 cases. I'd go for a home-made function otherwise...

Comment: For all the questions the answer is no..nothing is generalized ..for the last question as of now all are preceded by FDG_. I will put all the values soon.

Comment: @JvdV I dont have all the 25 records but i have added some.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey-- Thanks !! The provide formula is working fine..i dont think we can make it any more simpler!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Get Names UDF

In Excel e.g. for the value in `A1` use it like this:

```
=getNames(A1)
```

or if case-insensitive (A=a,B=b) use:

```
=getNames(A1,1)
```

[image]

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function getNames(SearchString As String, _
  Optional CaseInSensitive1 As VbCompareMethod = 0) As String

    Dim SearchNames, ReturnNames, i As Long

    ' Add more values when needed. This can also be written to
    ' retrieve values from a range.
    SearchNames = Array("Bank", _
                        "CTAS", _
                        "PDM")

    ReturnNames = Array("FDG_Bank_Material", _
                        "FDG_CTAS_Data", _
                        "FDG_PDM_Sensitive")

    For i = 0 To UBound(SearchNames)
        If InStr(1, SearchString, SearchNames(i), CaseInSensitive1) <> 0 Then
            getNames = ReturnNames(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```